# Create Official Dedicated CS:GO Server

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

I would like to make a CS:GO Server that people using the in-game casual matchmaking system can join.

But every time I make it it is created as a 'Community Dedicated' server as opposed to an 'Official Dedicated' one.

Does that mean that matchmaking only works on CS:GO Servers run by Valve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now only official Valve servers can be joined through either casual or competitive matchmaking.

Community servers must be joined by using the "Browse Community Servers" menu under "Play".